# How to get the number of Period between two dates with Jodatime?

Tags: java, jodatime

For experienced java developers, I guess this is a simple JodaTime question.

#### The problem

Given two DateTime `d1`, `d2` and a Period `p`, I want to know the first DateTime after `d2` that is `d1 + k * p` where `k` is an integer.

This is a simple question, and I can solve it using a loop. I would like to know if there is any contracted way in java. I mean can it be done in one line or two?

#### My idea so far

I think we have `k = (d2 - d1) % p` then we can get the correct date by adding `k+1 * p` to `d1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Period` being a wrapper of `long`, you can do:

```
long between = d2.getMillis() - d1.getMillis();
long period = p.getMillis();
int k = between / period + 1;
DateTime firstAfter = d1.plusMillis(k * p);
```

Comment: Cool, I will test this.

Comment: You might want to check if ``between % period == 0`` to add 1 or not (in which case ``firstAfter`` == ``d2``)